# How to ask for clarification from editor on suggested edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have an answer that a user (with low reputation) has suggested edits on:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25841208

I'm a little confused about the rationale behind their suggested edit and haven't been able to find a reference for the *need* for their edits, but I suspect it's correct.  I'd like to modify the edit slightly, but first I need to understand the reason for it.

Problem is, I see no way to contact the user, they don't seem to be on chat (they don't have the reputation for it), and there is no way to comment in a suggested edit page.

Any suggestions? Is the only answer to ask the question on Stack Exchange of "why was this edit suggested?" - it seems like it would be fishing for an answer when presumably the editor has the specifics.

Comment: You can't contact the user in the current state. only if you accept the edit you can @-mention them in a comment (but do note their username will not autocomplete, but it does work)

Comment: @Rob That question is not applicable here, since that is about replying to editors whose edits have *already been rejected*, while this question and the one I linked are about notifying editors whose edits are *still pending*.